# Issues getting CSS sprite made by me working

Tags: html, css, image, sprite, css-sprites

I made a CSS sprite using [this](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/) online site. [Here](https://mega.co.nz/#!V08EHZTL!rEZtYsMLwPhWNHytk47vPoEplWCJh0NKOOpP1PXB8fg) are the files I'm using. This is what I have right now in my HTML markup:

```
<img width="1" height="1" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="" title="" class="e-shop" />
```

Since `src` can't be null I set a empty GIF in base64. Now, the problem is that the `sprite.png` file isn't loaded. So I modified the original code changing to this:

```
.contactenos, .contactenos-1, img.e-shop, .e-shop-1, .faq, .faq-1, .fctjur, .fctjur-1, .fctnat, .fctnat-1, .vendidos, .vendidos-1{
    background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;
}
```

But it's not working, maybe I'm doing something wrong, it's the first time I did this, any advice or help?

**Test 1**

I made some changes to the original CSS as follow:

```
.contactenos, .e-shop, .faq, .fctjur, .fctnat, .vendidos {
    background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;
}

.e-shop{
    background-position: -198px -2px ;
    width: 128px;
    height: 50px;
}

.e-shop:hover {
    background-position: -200px -56px ;
    width: 128px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

But still not working, is the problem the tiny default `src` image?

Comment: I don't think that base64 string code works at all, usually the strings are way longer that than, even for small pictures, yours is way to short.

Comment: Can you put the relevant code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to see? It's easier that way than to imagine it ourselves.

Comment: @flowstoneknight I don't know how to include the sprite image on Fiddle for that I not able to reproduce the scenario, anyway just get a simple HTML markup, include the CSS and nothing else, use the same img I leave in the main topic

Comment: @Allan take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/) is not the same string as I have in base64 but is short too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your entire CSS, then you're missing a few things. Here's a fiddle using your markup and CSS (with a hard coded background image):

http://jsfiddle.net/5jvdmzgc/

You'll need to specify your elements `width` and `height` (right now, they're `1x1`) and also the offset of the background image (if any).

Updated CSS:

```
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
background-position: -70px -120px;
```

Updated fiddle with different sizes specified:

http://jsfiddle.net/5jvdmzgc/1/

You can use the CSS you wrote as a "base" (specifies the image source), and then extend that with individual classes (width/height/bg offsets).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: All them need to have the same heigth/width or can be different?

Comment: They can be different - It'll be based on your needs! I'll update the fiddle with additional elements with different sizes and offsets.

Comment: Thanks let me know for check!

Comment: @ReynierPM I used your markup for my fiddle (transparent 1x1 binary 64 image) - I actually think it's an issue with the "sprite.png". Can you verify that the file is being loaded? (If you're familiar with Chrome Developer Tools, you can check to make sure it's being requested..)

Comment: can you take a look [here](http://tanane.com/tanane/web/ml)? There should be the sprite and if you inspect the code you'll see the CSS and the route loaded, in localhost (dev server) it's work but there in prod server isn't and I don't know the cause, any advice?

Comment: Hi @ReynierPM - Can you verify this image path on your server: http://tanane.com/bundles/template/images/sprites.png (That's where the image is suppose to live) Which program do you use to transfer files from localhost to production server?

Comment: Well I can't find why this fail but this is the path I'm using on localhost (development) `/bundles/template/images/sprites.png` and it works perhaps because the VirtualHost is pointing to the complete path `/var/www/html/tanane/web`, now at production the right route is this `http://tanane.com/tanane/web/bundles/template/images/sprites.png` how should I rewrite this?

Comment: @ReynierPM I was going to comment, but it looks like you got it working :)

Comment: Opppss yes, you're right I didn't notice before, some cache issue with browser but yes leave the comment for others since I get things working now and many thanks for your time and support

Answer (score 1):

Your gif is only 1px by 1px. So your bg image is not going to be visible. You'll need to either set the dimensions in your css or provide a gif with the correct dimensions.

For example if your background image/sprite was 50px by 50px you could do this:

```
img.e-shop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

or

```
<img  class="e-shop" src="
R0lGODlhMgAyAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAyADIAAAIzhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKicFADs=
" />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk62s81t/)